# ChatGPT user prompt query to compare values in SQL Server table

Tags: openai-api, chat-gpt-4

Can anyone help in sharing chat-gpt user prompt message to get below metrics from SQL Server Table

SQLTable: APIResponse

| APIName | ResponseTimeInSecs | RunID | RunDate |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| API1 | 5 | 22 | 2023-11-22 | 2009-06-15T13:45:30 |
| API2 | 7 | 22 | 2023-11-22 | 2009-06-15T13:45:30 |
| API3 | 8 | 22 | 2023-11-22 | 2009-06-15T13:45:30 |
| API1 | 5 | 25 | 2023-11-22 | 2009-06-15T15:45:30 |
| API2 | 2 | 25 | 2023-11-22 | 2009-06-15T15:45:30 |
| API3 | 3 | 25 | 2023-11-22 | 2009-06-15T15:45:30 |

```
a. Get APINames who has performance improvement in RunID 25 when compared to  RunID 22
This will return below result
APIName, ResponseTimeinSecs, RunID
API2,2,25
API3,3,25

b. Get APINames who has performance improvement in latest Run when compared to  previous run
This will return below result. Based on RunDate, RunID 25 is latest and 22 is previous run so it needs to compare 25 with 22.
APIName, ResponseTimeinSecs, RunID
API1,2,25
API2,3,25
```

Comment: Team, appreciate if anyone can help on above query